# laravel 5.6 passport .Postman loading no output

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm trying to build an authentication endpoint where a user's key is returned when they are authenticated using `Laravel 5.6`.

When testing on `Postman` using `localhost:8000`, I find that it accepts the request but fails to output anything. [please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Pgr.png) .

Take a look at the `AuthController` below:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use Hash;

    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = User::firstOrNew(['email' => $request->email]);

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        $http = new Client;

        $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' =>'5G7yDJFNDsqzVNSJU85ff8DWW6EiKFLGXDDmMmt9',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
            ],
        ]);

    return response(['data'=>json_decode((string)$response->getBody(),true)]);

    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user) {
       return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'user not found']);
        }
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {

            $http = new Client;

            $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => '2',
              'client_secret' => 'JhzSRlU6dnJxI1vb8MpWWksjaOo3AdyuL3Mm6ANf',
                    'username' => $request->email,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    'scope' => '',
                ],
            ]);

        }
    }
    }
```

this is the code of user model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

this is the code of **api**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: I think this is from a youtube tutorial. If you get a chance, the user put up a new video called 'Complete Api Authentication with Laravel Passport'. The code is a bit different and seems to work better than his last one. Good luck!

Comment: yep it is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing in here is that, you may change your postman request as follows,

1. add Headers as follows.[image: image1]
2. add Body as form-data[image: image2]

Most importantly check your port is correct that the laravel server is running. Default port is port 8000. Then your url should formed as

> http://localhost:8000/api/register (note that this url is only an example format)

Try to make above changes and give us what you've got. Think this may help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when using `php artisan serve`, it uses a  PHP server which is [single-threaded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

You can do this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223483/912900):

> When making calls to itself the thread blocked waiting for its own reply. The solution is to either seperate the providing application and consuming application into their own instance or to run it on a multi-threaded webserver such as Apache or nginx.

Or if you are looking for a quick fix to test your updates - you can get this done by opening up two command prompts. The first would be running `php artisan serve` (locally my default port is 8000 and you would be running your site on `http://localhost:8000`). The second would run `php artisan serve --port 8001`.

Then you would update your post request to:

```
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8001/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '2',
            'client_secret' =>'5G7yDJFNDsqzVNSJU85ff8DWW6EiKFLGXDDmMmt9',
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);
```

This should help during your testing until you are able to everything on server or a local virtual host.