# GuzzleHttp\Client don't return any response

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i'm creating an authentication api using passport from the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) but i'm stuck on sending GuzzelHttp request

i'v done exactly like the docs but when i want to test with postman no result returned it just stay loading without end

this is my code
my controller

```
$user = new User();
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        $http = new Client;

        $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 2,
                'client_secret' => 'x2ESrkADoQEaQ91iMW9kKiIvjKo0LL4RxlUtqtmy',
                'password' => $request->password
            ],
        ]);
        dd($response);

        return response([
            'success'=> true,
            'successMessageKey' => 'userCreatedSuccessfully' ,
            'data'=>json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)
        ]);
```

and my route

```
Route::post('users/register',[
'uses' => 'Api\AuthController@register'
]);
```

and when i run my route i got no result like this and stuck in loading

[image: error]

Comment: Try changing it from `raw` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman and add the parameters that way.

Comment: i tried but the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when using `php artisan serve`, it uses a  PHP server which is [single-threaded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

You can do this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223483/912900):

> When making calls to itself the thread blocked waiting for its own reply. The solution is to either seperate the providing application and consuming application into their own instance or to run it on a multi-threaded webserver such as Apache or nginx.

Or if you are looking for a quick fix to test your updates - you can get this done by opening up two command prompts. The first would be running `php artisan serve` (locally my default port is 8000 and you would be running your site on `http://localhost:8000`). The second would run `php artisan serve --port 8001`.

Then you would update your post request to:

```
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8001/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'x2ESrkADoQEaQ91iMW9kKiIvjKo0LL4RxlUtqtmy',
            'password' => $request->password
        ],
    ]);
```

This should help during your testing until you are able to everything on server or a local virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Try including **password_confirmation** in your parameters in Postman. That's what I did in my laravel passport project

Comment: the problem is not in parameters because i tried the same request in guzzle by postman and it works fine , the problem here is with guzzle

Comment: Ahhh okay. Try: instead of $http = new Client;... put this 
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client

Answer (score -1):

I findout the problem in your code

please check the parameter which you sent to auth/token. username is missing in your request

Comment: yes i know i removed it just for test, because i want to see just a response, so i tried to removed it to see a ( parameterMissing ) response but also i didn't see anything

Answer (score -1):

You need pass array of `form_params` as json

e.g

```
$response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => json_encode([
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 2,
                'client_secret' => 'x2ESrkADoQEaQ91iMW9kKiIvjKo0LL4RxlUtqtmy',
                'password' => $request->password
            ]),
 ]);
```

Comment: i think it must be an Array, i tried ur example and it show me this err    "message": "http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object.  Incorrect value given"

Comment: also pass `headers => ['Accept' => 'application/json']`