# AWS Amazon Server : cURL error could not resolve host

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, guzzle

I've been using a **fanless ubuntu server** for a couple of months and been transferred my `Laravel API Passport` to different servers like `Ubuntu` and for development `Windows`.

The current version of my api is working fine on these servers. Not until when I transferred the laravel project to my `AWS Amazon server` and getting the error like this

```
{
"message": "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api-a.mydomain.comoauth (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
"exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException",
"file": "/var/www/html/api_tk_a/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php",
"line": 185,
"trace": [
{
   ....some line of multiple errors
}
]
```

}

I tried to add some line of code to my `etc/hosts` file

like this

`52.***.***.205 api-a.mydomain.com
 52.***.***.205 api-b.mydomain.com`

or

`127.0.0.1 api-a.mydomain.com
 127.0.0.1 api-b.mydomain.com`

tried also my `inet addr:171.*.**.**` to put on my `hosts` file still getting the same error

I have 2 different `api` that's why there's `a` and `b`

But nothing of these works.

Can anyone point out the reason why I'm getting this error.

Some thread says this has nothing to do with the `Guzzle` but clearly states to the `IP` and `DNS`. But I can't find a good way to figure this out.

**UPDATE**

My `.env` file has something like this

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1AEVUl5JHMzLkhxU7MDlDHtfZ6KB9UybjzUxLaYp9vg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

I tried to put the `APP_URL` as `https://api-a.mydomain.com` still not working..

API CODE `This code is working fine`

```
$http = new Client;
        $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [
            'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '2',
            'client_secret' => '8mEsN0RZkljKZlbiJFfnNKahcbcOVkoQVG7C2Xwl',
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
            ],
        ]);
```

This is my `routes/api.php`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('/login','Auth\Api\AuthController@login');
```

`EC2` Ping

[image]

Comment: domains api-a.mydomain.com and api-b.mydomain.com are point to your EC2?

Comment: ec2-user@52.***.***.205, yes. Hmm is there any connection with my `ec2` and my error?

Comment: can you check inbound rules for EC2? Because to access from outside to EC2 we must be defined inbound rules for EC2.

Comment: How can I check my `inbound rules for EC2` ?

Comment: Go to list Instances, and select to your instances. After that show info of Descriptions panel (like as http://prntscr.com/orvz8o)

Comment: You can try to add  All traffic to your EC2 by: Type is All Traffic, Protocal is All, Port Rage is All, Source is 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Me and my colleague trying to follow your instruction what's next sir?

Comment: done with adding all traffic to my EC2 but still getting the same error and tried to restart my httpd using this command `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: Have you tried to ping to your domain? and what is result? can you try replace your domain by Public IP of EC2 instance.

Comment: I tried to enter my public ip of ec2 to browser and the login interface of laravel `/public/index.php` shows but when I tried to send a request from postman to api guzzle cURL still showing

Comment: Can you show your code of api function?

Comment: Sorry late reply had my lunch, I updated my post when codes is included

Comment: Does the subnet have access to the internet via an Internet Gateway or a Nat Gateway? Check the security groups and network access control lists as well.

Comment: In the error message, this looks like a string concat issue. "api-a.mydomain.comoauth"

Comment: I didn't change anything on my backend. Maybe this is on the godaddy or aws server. I will try to check on it

Comment: what would be the reason why `oauth` is with `.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I used `$http->post('https://api-a.mydomain.com' . '/oauth/token', [`

[Laravel passport trying to get oauth/token. Guzzle keeps hanging, also on other Guzzle calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797452/laravel-passport-trying-to-get-oauth-token-guzzle-keeps-hanging-also-on-other)

Answer (score 0):

For ping to work in EC2 instance, you have to open ICMP port in Security Group for your IP. Also for curl, verify have you opened port 8080/80 for your instance.